# Convert SQL query to linq asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
SELECT 
    O.OrderID, p.ProductName, op.Quantity, 
    m.MemberName, (op.Price * op.Quantity) as Total Price
FROM 
    o order, op order_product, m member, p product
WHERE 
    o.orderID = op.OrderID
    AND op.ProductID = p.ProductID
    AND o.MemberID = m.MemberID
    AND o.OrderDateTime = @selectDate;
GROUP BY 
    o.OrderID
```

I am new to the Linq. Does anyone know how to convert this SQL statement to linq?

I know this query was inefficient, but I am still learning. I want to produce the daily transaction report which can group the Order ID.

I am trying my best to write the LinQ by myself but how did i combine 4 table?

```
        var query = from o in db.order_product
                    where o.order.OrderDateTime == System.DateTime.Now
                    group o by o.order
                    into OrderList
                    select new {
                        OrderID = OrderList.Key.OrderID,
                        ProductName = OrderList.Key.order_product
                    };
```

I need to get the Order ID (In order table), product name (In product table), quantity (In order_product table)and member name(In member table).

Comment: There are online tool available which converts SQL to LINQ. Check this : http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: If you are learning, then you probably have tried something, but it didn't work. Please add your LINQ query to question. We will tell you what went wrong and how to solve your problem

Comment: @Paresh J I cant use it because it doesnt support MySQL..

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy opps, i edit my post. I was trying to produce the Daily Transaction Report.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools available for this like LinqPad, SqlToLinq.
For the question, try something like below:

```
    var retResult = from o in dbContext.order 
                    inner join op in dbContext.order_product
                    on o.orderID equals op.OrderID

                    inner join p in dbContext.product
                    on op.ProductID equals p.ProductID

                    inner join m in dbContext.member
                    on o.MemberID equals m.MemberID

                    group o by o.OrderId into og
                    where o.OrderDateTime = @selectDate

                    select new { 
                                    OrderID = O.OrderID, 
                                    ProductName = p.ProductName, 
                                    Quantity = op.Quantity, 
                                    MemberName = m.MemberName, 
                                    TotalPrice = (op.Price * op.Quantity) 
                               }
```

Comment: `where o.OrderDateTime = @selectDate` the `o` is not in current context.

Answer (score 0):

joining tables is fairly simple. In your case you need inner join and that is the easiest one. Simply append `from` clauses with inner join condition

```
var query = from op in db.order_product.Where(o=>o.order.OrderDateTime == System.DateTime.Now)
            from o in db.order.Where(o=>o.Id == op.OrderId)
            from p in db.product.Where(p=>p.Id == op.ProductId)
            from m in db.member.Where(m=>m.Id == o.MemberId)
            group op by op.order
                into OrderList
                select new {
                    OrderID = OrderList.Key.OrderID,
                    ProductName = OrderList.Key.order_product.Name,
                    Quantity = OrderList.Key.order_product.Quantity,
                    MemberName = OrderList.Key.Member.Name
                };
```

Hope it helps,
Alessandro